# Ormlite saving wrong day of date, depending on the hour of the day

Tags: java, android, date, ormlite

I capture current data via javascript and send it to java so it can be saved to the database because I have an application in Cordova.

I've checked the date that is sent to the db by the function for the update (below), and the date returned is "Fri Aug 09 23:56:03 GMT-03: 00 2019" (2019-08-09 23:56:03) however the date saved in the database is (2019-08-10 23:56:03)

It happens normally after 21 o'clock

```
private boolean atualizarObjeto(Objeto parObj) throws SQLException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
    if (parObj == null) {
        return false;
    }

    Dao<Objeto, Object> objDAO = obterDAO(parObj);
    Hashtable<String,String> tblHashCampos = obterInfoClasseCampos(objDAO, parObj.getClass());
    TableInfo infoTabela = new TableInfo(objDAO.getConnectionSource(), (BaseDaoImpl) objDAO, parObj.getClass());
    UpdateBuilder<Objeto, Object> updateBuilder = objDAO.updateBuilder();

    //Preenche campos para atualizacao
    preencherCamposUpdateRecursivo( tblHashCampos, updateBuilder, parObj.getClass(), parObj );
    //Where --> ID
    FieldType campoID = infoTabela.getIdField();
    Object id = objDAO.extractId( parObj );
    updateBuilder.where().eq( campoID.getColumnName(), id);
    //Atualiza
    updateBuilder.prepare();
    infoTabela = null;
    //Log.d("esus-mobile", "SQL: " + updateBuilder.prepareStatementString());
    if (updateBuilder.update() > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I checked the date in the function "preencherCamposUpdateRecursivo" because it is the function responsible for filling each field value in update query

Comment: Wonder if you could [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please? It sounds like a time zone problem, however, it’s weird that the time of day seems to be correct/unchanged, then.

Comment: At the moment I do not have enough time to create a minimal and reproducible example, I also suspected something related to the time zone but could not verify. And besides, I suspect this does not happen in the codes I coded, but in the transition from the java object to the DB record.

Comment: Doing more tests I realized that this happens after 21 o'clock, which reaffirms even more time zone problem because as I am in Brazil my time zone is GMT -3